# Linux IPTables-Based Reverse Proxy

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, nat

I have 2 Public IPs on a VPS and a residential network connection:

VPS = **55.55.55.55**

Residential = **66.66.66.66**

The VPS all this is done on is a **Debian 11** system with minimal changes.

I would like to have external public connections to **55.55.55.55** over **port 8888** be nat'ed to **66.66.66.66** and have session traffic return to the external public from 66.66.66.66 through **55.55.55.55**.

Basically I want to host something on **55.55.55.55** but I dont want people to know my true IP as I plan on using **66.66.66.66** as IPS security (not setup/installed yet).

```
                                     [VPS]
                                  66.66.66.66
                                    |     |
                                    |     |
                                    |     |
              -----------------------     -----------------------
              |                                                 |
         55.55.55.55                                    Ex. 234.123.166.123
[Residential ISP Connection]                                [Internet]
```

From what I've seen I have ran the following commands and they *should* work but it seems that traffic is received then not forwarded.

```
## Clear all entries and add ssh
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && \
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP && \
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && \
sudo iptables -t nat -F && \
sudo iptables -t mangle -F && \
sudo iptables -F && \
sudo iptables -X && \
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT && \
sleep 1 && \
sudo iptables-save 

## Allow Traffic
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Setup NAT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 20071 -j DNAT --to-destination 55.55.55.55:8888
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20071 -j SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66

## Save
sudo iptables-save
```

Again, I can see the traffic coming in on port **8888** from the external internet, but nothing leaving and the **55.55.55.55** firewall is receiving nothing in terms of packets from **66.66.66.66** (aside from ssh ofcourse).

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables doesn't work on the same level as reverse proxies – your setup doesn't cause the VPS itself to accept TCP connections; it redirects the individual packets at IP level. (Basically there's a reason the chain that holds NAT rules is named "pre-routing"...)

In other words, traffic that DNAT is applied to is no longer *input* traffic – it becomes *forwarded* traffic. That means your 'INPUT' rules are irrelevant here and what you need is a 'FORWARD' rule that allows packets to be sent to the new DNAT destination – and another rule that allows *replies* to be sent from that host as well.

Right now your entire `FORWARD` table in iptables ruleset consists of:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

so the packets cannot be forwarded.

---

In general I would not recommend doing this for proxying; it is usually better to *tunnel* the packets unmodified, as that way your home server would be able to see the original client IP addresses (instead of thinking that all connections come from the VPS). You could use a plaintext tunnel such as GRE, or an encrypted one such as WireGuard or OpenVPN.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes you have the wrong tool for the job.